# Speeding up TIF import

Tags: import, image

After trying to import a $\approx 2$ GB TIF file with the Import command, I noticed that the process takes $\approx 15$ minutes or so, which seems excessive, especially when compared to other software packages.  Attempting to load TIF files $>10$ GB in size can take over an hour.  Surely there must be some trick to accelerate the import procedure?  If not, can anyone explain to me why this is occurring?  Perhaps it is generating an index of the individual images in some inefficient manner?

I have a 64-bit system and I'm happy to use an arbitrary amount of memory - speed is what matters to me.

Comment: What amount of physical memory does your computer have?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries 128 GB of RAM.

Comment: Ohhhkay... What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It's a stack of 256 x 256 pixel images with real numbered pixel values?

Comment: Just trying to estimate the uncompressed memory footprint. So, how many images in that stack?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It's going to be between 4,000 to 6,000 images in the stack.  However, for larger files, there might be as many as 50,000 images.

Comment: 6000 should be around 9 GB and 50,000 around 73 GB. It's huge, but it should fit. However, I can imagine that it needs extra temporary memory while loading and unpacking. It's also possible that it uses temporary files too. That will take quite some time in this case. Perhaps it can be saved as a raw binary?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The trouble is that it loads very quickly (seconds) in LabView.  Would it significantly help to change it into a raw binary format?  Also, thanks for your help here.

Comment: Is it any faster loading it as data?

Comment: @Corey Kelly I'm not seeing a significant speedup... hmm

Comment: (I suspect that you want a purely Mathematica function but) Have you tried to import with libtiff via MathLink?  If you do a lot of reading, maybe it's worth investigating it.

Comment: Would image file processing like in `ImageFileScan` or `ImageFileApply` do any good?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I investigated as per your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to help much.

Comment: You do end your `Import` statement with a ; do you?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure it will help in your case (it depends on exactly what your files contain), but you can sometimes import just pieces/elements of a file instead of the whole thing. For example, you can check what kind of information a file contains using

```
Import["ExampleData/rose.gif", "Elements"]

{"Animation", "AnimationRepetitions", "Background", "BitDepth",
 "ColorMap", "ColorSpace", "Comments", "Data", "DataType",
 "DisplayDurations", "Frames", "GlobalColorMap", "Graphics",
 "GraphicsList", "GrayLevels", "Image", "ImageCount", "ImageList",
 "ImageSize", "RawData", "RGBColorArray", "TransitionEffect", "UserInputFlag"}
```

and then choose to import only those parts that you need to work with, for example:

```
Import["ExampleData/rose.gif", "GrayLevels"]
```

Answer (score 4):

I cannot confirm your timings.

```
 AbsoluteTiming[
   data = ConstantArray[
    Image[ConstantArray[4095, {1024, 1024}], "Bit16"], 768]; 
 Export["C:\\Users\\stelzer\\Desktop\\test.tif", data, "TIFF"];
(* {6.765371, Null} *)

FileByteCount["C:\\Users\\stelzer\\Desktop\\test.tif"]
(* 1611793936 *)

AbsoluteTiming[
 dataIn = Import["C:\\Users\\stelzer\\Desktop\\test.tif", "TIFF"];]
(* {10.086806, Null} *)

Length /@ {data, dataIn}
(* {768, 768} *)
```

Comment: Seems to scale worse with the number of frames: `Export["~/test.tif", Table[Image[Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 256}, {j, 1, 256}]], {k, 1, 5000}], "TIFF"];
First@AbsoluteTiming[Import["~/test.tif", "TIFF"];]` is about 3 minutes on my system (which is pretty old.)