# Slow import of multigigabyte TIF image stacks

Tags: performance-tuning, import, image

**Update 6:** After contacting Wolfram Technical Support, I was advised that the frame-to-frame import timing variability can be eliminated by reading in the frame stack from frame to frame with the commands:

```
data[[k]] = Import["multiframe.tiff", {"ImageList", k}]
```

or

```
data[[k]] = Import["multiframe.tiff", {"GraphicsList", k}]
```

My response was:

If we write a simple script like this:

```
StackDepth = Import["...\\data.tif", "ImageCount"]

data = Array[0 &, StackDepth];
TimingArray = Array[0 &, StackDepth];

For[i = 1, i <= StackDepth, i++,  
    FrameStartTime = AbsoluteTime[];
         data[[i]] = Import["...\\data.tif", {"GraphicsList", i}];

   FrameEndTime = AbsoluteTime[];
   TimeArray[[i]] = FrameEndTime - FrameStartTime;

     Print[i, "   ", TimeArray[[i]]];
];
```

For a 10,000 frame stack, where individual frames have dimensions {256,256}, we have a ~0.85 second per frame import time (implying that it will take 10^4*0.85 seconds ~ 2.5 hours to load in all of the frames.  So the loading times are actually longer than just using   data[[i]] = Import["...\data.tif"];.

Also, if we try a 5,000 frame stack, we have a ~0.5 second / frame loading time.

So it seems this fix just spreads out the slow loading time to all frames.

Is there a way around this or a patch?

---

I noticed that it takes half an hour or so for me to import a $\approx 1.86$ GB TIF file consisting of exactly 15,000 images with 256 x 256 pixels (via the Import[] command), whereas it takes only a few seconds to load the same file in a program like ImageJ.  My machine has 128 gigs of ram, and a fairly modern Xeon processor, so I doubt that's the issue.  I'm hoping to understand why this is happening, and what, if anything, I can do about it.

Because of the device I'm using to capture the images, it would be very helpful to import files in this TIF format.  That said, it doesn't seem to help to try other image formats like PNG.

---

For an example, I've uploaded the exact TIF file I'm using, which is again a stack with exactly 15,000 images, each consisting of a {256, 256} pixel lattice, to the following dropbox folder:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xdztnk4iykjabb/ExampleTIF.tif (to retrieve the file, click "download" in the upper-right-hand corner).

The first {256, 256} frame of the TIF file ($\approx 128$ kb in size) can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o85s74rdi33hq76/frame1.tif (unfortunately, you have to download the image to see it, as the preview appears to be broken).

I have clocked that it takes 1528.1894075 seconds (about 25 minutes and 28 seconds) to load the full TIF stack with the command:

```
data = Import["E:\\data\\ExampleTIF.tif"];
```

The loading time I observe for the single frame appears to be $\approx 24$ milliseconds, which implies that the full stack should load in $24$ milliseconds $\times 15,000$ frames $\approx 6 $ minutes.  The $24$ millisecond loading time per frame seems excessive in and of itself without accounting for the factor of 4-5x per-frame slowdown when loading the full stack.  Why is ImageJ, LabVIEW, etc. so much faster than Mathematica?  I can load the full stack in less than 30 seconds with either of these programs.

---

I previously asked this question here: [Speeding up TIF import](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27875/speeding-up-tif-import) without an explicit example.  Unfortunately I lost my account log-in information, and was unable to update the old question.

---

**Update 5:**  In the comments section, Simon Woods wrote:

"To see what Import is actually doing with those functions you could do a trace like this: With[{syms = Alternatives @@ Symbol /@ Names["*`*TIFF*"]}, Trace[Import["frame1.tif"], syms, TraceInternal -> True]]"

Here's the result of that trace analysis:

```
{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{Image`ImportExportDump`ImageFrameCountTIFF["E:\\data\\ExampleTIF.tif"], 15000}}},{{{Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF["E:\\data\\ExampleTIF.tif"], {IMAGES FROM TIFF STACK HERE}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

As can be clearly seen, Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF, which is the same function I've analyzed the behavior of below, is being used for the TIFF stack import.  Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTiledTIFF[] & Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTileTIFF[] remain mystery functions.

---

**Update 4:** There appears to be some metadata for my TIFF stack.  Running the command:

```
Import["E:\\data\\ExampleTIF.tif", "Table"]
```

Returns:

```
{{"II*\.00ü", "\.02\.00Andor", 
  "SOLIS\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\
\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00\.00t\.0e\.0fB"}, {"`"}, {"l"}, {"i"}, {"å\.0eÕ
  \.08"}, {"P\.10%\.0e0\.11\.10I\.0f\.06\.11L\[RawEscape]42O<\
\[Divide])»\.19Â\.0f
  Í\.10"}, {"æ
  ½"}, {""}, {"T"}, {"õ\.11g"}, {"\.0e1\.0f\.02\.11Þ\.10Y\.10â\.11\
\.1c\.11]\.15l\.1dG44É%s\.15
  \.12L\.0f"}, {"\.10õ"}, {""}, {"­\.0f>\.0e\.1d\.12Ç
  Å\.10ç\.0e\.1c\.0fç\.0fý\.0eR\.0f\.0ea\.0e\.0b\.0b\.06\.0e"}, {}, \
{"3\.0eÆ\.0f\.0f
  î\.0b\[Paragraph]\.0eb\.0e¹
  %\.0fÏ\.0eû\.0fA\.0e\.b4

  »\.0f\.10\.12\.11X\.0ei\.10ñ\.10ò\.0eÊ\.0f\.15\.0fk\.10=\.10\.0e¡\
\.11R
  A\.0bä\.0eL\.0f¹\.0fØ\.10â\.0e\[PlusMinus]\.0e\.13\.0f~
  æ
  "}, {"¢
  Ü\.0f9"}, {"W\.0e|
  t"}, {"Æ
  \.14\.0f"}, {"ê\.11{\.11º\.10\.0e¨\.0fõ
  \.0fT"}, {"\.07"}, {"É"}, {"\.10¼
  \.1f\.0f\.0eì\.13R\.10Å\.10Q\.11B\.0fÁ"}, {"\.10\.08"}, {"l\.10Ô\
\.12j"}, {".\.0eü\.0eÓ\.0fð\.0f\.18\.0f"}, {"\.0f­\.10Þ"}, {"é"}, \
{"I"}, {"0
  \.0ea\.0b\.0bÍ\.0bj"}, {"%\.0eB\.10=\.0b[
  \[Paragraph]\.0e\.16\.0b3"}, {}, {"\.0b\[Micro]"}, {"Ö\.0f\""}, {"p\
\.0fú"}, {"w
  \.0fB\.12E"}, {"Å
  Þ"}, {"\.04\.0e¨\.0fÃ\.0b)\.0fÁ\.0eÆ"}, {"Ñ"}, {"m\.0f \.0fû\.10:\
\.0f("}, {"x\.0f\.06\.0f¾\.10¨\.10(\.10½"}, {"ø\.0bW\.0b<

  U"}, {"I"}, {"T\.10\.1c\.0el\.11ò

  ¿
  \.10ä\.0e\[Paragraph]"}, {"N\.0f\.02\.0f\.13\.0eÛ\.0eã
  \[Degree]
  \.05"}, {"H\.0e\.0fô
  "}, {"\.0f5
  0\.0b«\.0e«\.0f.
  §\.0f7\.10+\.0e"}}
```

Most of this looks like junk, but you can see the name of the camera used to collect the data as well as some optical setup specifications.  Perhaps there's a way to strip this data out and prevent whatever trigger is causing Mathematica to repeatedly scan through the image stack?

---

**Update 3:** I've updated the second figure to show that the import time for a fixed set of $N = 100$ frames exhibits reliable linear scaling with the depth of the first frame, $k$, in the image stack.

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF[]
```

Is clearly the wrong tool to use to import a large stack of TIF files.  I also think that, after some handwringing (leading to a delay in importing a single frame), this is probably the function that Import[] calls when passed the ExampleTIF.tif stack.

However, I haven't been able to get:

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTiledTIFF[] 
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTileTIFF[]
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadStripedTIFF[] (striped?)
```

To work at all.  Perhaps one of these functions represents a way forward?  That said, I can't even set of arguments that these functions need.

---

**Update 2:**

Ok, let's do some experiments to help elucidate the cause underlying slow loading times for large TIF stacks.  First, based on Simon Wood's observation, notice that we can use:

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageFrameCountTIFF["E:\\data\\ExampleTIF.tif"]
```

To return an integer value corresponding to the number of frames in the TIF image stack.  We can then use:

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF["E:\\data\\ExampleTIF.tif", Table[i, {i, StartFrame, EndFrame}]]
```

To return the set of frames including and between specifiable StartFrame and EndFrame integer variables.

[image]

First we notice that, setting StartFrame = 1, linearly increasing the number of frames we want to import (by linearly increasing EndFrame) requires what appears to be a quadratically scaling amount of time.

[image]

Secondly, we can notice that attempting to import a fixed length stack of 100 frames has a time-cost that scales with the depth of the 100 frames in the stack.  In other words, for some {StartFrame, EndFrame} pair, the frame set including and between {StartFrame+k,EndFrame+k} appears to take a longer time to load, and this delay appears to linearly scale with $k$.

So the trouble, I'm guessing, lies with properly indexing the TIF image stack.  Is there any clever way to fix this?

---

**Update 1:** Following up on Simon Wood's comment, entering ?*`*TIFF* in Mathematica v9.0 gives a set of functions, one of them being ImageReadTIFF.  However:

```
image = Image`ImageReadTIFF["E:\\data\\frame1.tif", All];
```

just returns:

```
Image`ImageReadTIFF["E:\\data\\frame1.tif", All]
```

Is there any obvious mistake on my part?

Comment: If I was in your situation, I'd upload a smaller file as well - say 3 or 4 images - so that people could see whether it was a file/format issue or just a scaling issue. (I'd like to help but, like many here, I have less than 10% of the RAM that you have...)

Comment: @cormullion That makes a lot of sense.  I've provided an additional link to the first {256, 256} frame of the TIF stack.  The file size is $\approx 128$ kb.

Comment: Yes, DropBox only previews smaller images, I seem to recall. Your image imports OK (just one frame?). I think the problem might be that your other software apps probably load pointers to individual frames rather than loading all the data at once. Mathematica on the other hand likes to have everything in memory (and only recently started introducing file-based image processing such as `ImageFileScan`). But I might be completely wrong...:)

Comment: @cormullion Right, that's probably true - though I can do plenty of operations on all the frames using ImageJ in a fraction of the time it takes to load the stack in Mathematica.  Even the 24 millisecond time to load that single frame seems excessive.

Comment: On version 8 I can use ``Image`ImageReadTIFF[filename, All]`` to load the single frame file about 120 times faster than `Import` does. I don't know if there are any nasty side effects or if it will work on the large file, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: @halirutan provided [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107889/calling-imagej-from-mathematica) to integrating imagej with Mathematica.  If imagej is indeed faster, perhaps letting it do the work for M is the right way to go.

Comment: @SimonWoods Is there a version 9 equivalent for Image`ImageReadTIFF[filename, All]?  What you say sounds extremely promising, but it doesn't seem to work on v9, and I no longer have any systems with version 8.

Comment: @SimonWoods I can't seem to find any documentation on ImageReadTIFF?

Comment: I don't have version 9 to check. You could try ``?*`*TIFF*`` to see if there are any likely looking functions anywhere else. The function isn't documented, it is used internally by `Import`.

Comment: @SimonWoods ImageReadTIFF seems to be there, but I can't get it to work?

Comment: ```Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF[file]``` but there's also ImageReadTiledTiff, ImageReadTileTiff, ImageFrameCountTIFF, ImageReadMetadataTIFF, ImageReadStripedTIFF ...

Comment: @cormullion I found the `ImageReadTIFF` when I traced `Import` but, on my machine calling this function is not really faster than using `Import`. Have you timed it?

Comment: @halirutan For the OP's single frame, it's 0.015 for `Import`, but 0.000745 for `ImageReadTIFF` on Mac/M9. That might be worth having. (I tried a `TracePrint` but it took over 20 minutes and printed thousands of lines of stuff.)

Comment: To see what `Import` is actually doing with those functions you could do a trace like this: ``With[{syms = Alternatives @@ Symbol /@ Names["*`*TIFF*"]}, Trace[Import["frame1.tif"], syms, TraceInternal -> True]]``

Comment: @SimonWoods Thanks, I'll run the script and post the result.

Comment: @SimonWoods I've posted the result of your script in Update 5.  Nothing terribly surprising I'm afraid.

Comment: BTW, I usually save the images from SOLIS in FITS format (actually, I asked some Andor personnel about this, and they specifically recommended this format as an alternative to their SIF that many of them actually use by default). Whether the files will be quicker to import I don't know, but if so, this would appear to be a viable approach.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks - I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: So, what happens if you read the image manually with `ImageFileScan`? Also, would it make sense to do some dynamic caching (loading single frames with memoization, so to speak)? `ImageFileScan` seems to support frames, but I am not sure if this applies to your TIFF images.

Comment: The future version of Mathematica will take care of this.

Comment: One would think Excel graphs are prohibited here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in the next version (10.0) of Mathematica.

Comment: Hello.  Please, who are you, and how do you know this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do not know who this is, however I did contact technical support and provided them to link here.  Perhaps this is someone from Wolfram Research?  I wonder if he means 9.something or version 10?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard There is someone with the same name working in a research position at Wolfram.

Comment: @SparsePine [So it seems.](http://www.linkedin.com/pub/piotr-wendykier/7/283/0) Piotr, I see that someone downvoted this answer.  That wasn't me, but it's not unexpected for a non-sequitur claim such as this.  I hope you will visit this site again, and please consider adding your affiliation to your profile.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah!  This is is what that name sounds familiar - http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/04/29/gigapixel-images-in-mathematica/

Comment: I'm a consultant at Wolfram Research. This particular TIFF file can be imported in less than 20 seconds using current build of Mathematica 10.

Comment: @PiotrWendykier Do you... have a release date estimate?  =)

Comment: @SparsePine The release date is not decided yet.