# Understanding the discrepancy between txt file import and export times, and possibly speeding up Import

Tags: import

I attempted to import a very short .txt file string using the `Import` command:

```
Import["C:\\TestFile.txt"] // AbsoluteTiming

Out: {0.020001, "Test"}
```

Why does this take 20 milliseconds?  `Export` is about an order of magnitude faster for the same string:

```
Import["C:\\TestFile.txt","Test"] // AbsoluteTiming

Out: {0.002000, "C:\\test.txt"}
```

Are there any hidden options for `Import` like the following (concerning TIF files) from a previous question of mine [Slow import of multigigabyte TIF image stacks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28506/slow-import-of-multigigabyte-tif-image-stacks)?:

```
Image`ImportExportDump`ImageReadTIFF
```

Quoting the user cormullion from my previous question: "For the OP's single frame, it's 0.015 for Import, but 0.000745 for ImageReadTIFF on Mac/M9. That might be worth having."

Comment: `Import` comes with a lot of overhead. Try for example `Import["testfile.txt", "Text"] // AbsoluteTiming` versus just `Import["testfile.txt"]` and that removes just one test `Import` has to make. Then try `ReadList["testfile.txt", "String"] // AbsoluteTiming` which hasn't got the same sort of overhead. Also try `Trace[Import["testfile.txt"]]` to see exactly the internal functions used and the kind of tests performed.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of reducing the number of questions that have been more or less thoroughly "answered in comments", I take the liberty to transform [Pickett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/pickett)'s [insightful comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31817/understanding-the-discrepancy-between-txt-file-import-and-export-times-and-poss#comment99214_31817) into an answer:

---

`Import` comes with a lot of overhead. Compare for example the following two snippets:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 ClearSystemCache[];
 Import["testfile.out"];
]

RepeatedTiming[
  ClearSystemCache[];
  Import["testfile.out", "Text"];
]

(*Out:
{0.329, Null}
{0.14, Null}
*)
```

Simply providing `Import` with information on the format of the data removes a lot of content testing overhead!

---

You can compare the performance of `Import` with that of functions that don't need to carry out as much testing on their input, e.g. `ReadList`:

```
RepeatedTiming[
  ClearSystemCache[]; 
  ReadList["testfile.out", "String"];
]

(*Out: {0.027, Null} *)
```

Also an interesting idea is to look at `Trace[Import["testfile.out"]]` to see exactly the internal functions used and the kind of tests performed.

Comment: I think you've got your initial timings backwards ...

Comment: @rcollyer I sure did! It's fixed now. Thank you for pointing that out!